# pre-compile jsp files on tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, precompile

I'm trying to improve jsp performance on my webapp.
Using jspc maven plugin, I've generated jsp class files and then I've inserted their mapping in web.xml.
When webapp starts on my local tomcat, it seems to load a little faster, but on server i can see any change. And furthermore, it seems to reload jsp for every request.

Is there any tomcat conf that I need change or set to avoid jsp reloading or recompilation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you by reload jsp for every request?is yor jsp recompile for every request?

Comment: I think so because in the next requests page load is slow in the same way as the first request.

Comment: the jsp file are  recompiled only and only if there is any change in it between your previous request and next request,other wise it doesn't need to be compiled,as for your slow reloading,there must be something else causing it.post your code to see it.

Comment: There is no change between requests. We are a single jsp page that includes others jsps (<jsp:include page="xxx.jsp">) and loads multiple js files in which it is implemented (using jquery and ajax calls) dynamic logic.